# Create dynamically angular component without ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-components

Is it possible to create dynamically angular (v2 or higher) component in any position of the DOM without using ng-content or any placeholder such as ng-template or a directive like ngComponentOutlet?

Comment: Yes, it;s possible

Comment: How can I achieve that? Can you show some code? Thank you.